# Declare templated class object when non type argument value to be known at run time : operator + overloading in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++17, c++20

I want to create a temp array object with length of array equal to sum of lengths of arr1 and arr2. How do I do it?
The following function is declared as friend in class array.

```
template<class T1, int l1>
array<T1, l1> operator +( const array<T1, l1> &arr1, const array<T1, l1> &arr2 )
{
    int add= arr1.size()+ arr2.size();
    array<T1, add> temp;
    ........
}
```

Here size() member function simply returns the length of data.
Class declaration is:

```
template<class T, int length>
class array
{
    T *data{};
 public:
  //Overloaded assignment operator taking arr object as parameter

    template<class T1, int l1>
    array& operator=(const array<T1, l1> &arr_copy);

    template<class T1, int l1>
    friend array<T1, l1> operator +( const array<T1, l1> &arr1, const array<T1, l1> &arr2 );

....Constructors and member functions....
};
```

This should work in main()->

```
arr3 = arr1 + arr2;
```

Anybody has any clue as to what can be done?
Where is return type resolver significant here?

Comment: Short answer is **no** if the values are only known at runtime. Templates resolve at compile time.

Comment: Can you suggest a way in which I can overload + operator to work as desired?

Comment: This is slowly but surely turning into an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't mean to be fixated on a particular Y. I'm quite stuck in this problem. Show me the way if you may

Comment: First, why is there a `T* data` for a templated `array` class?  Shouldn't that simply be `T data[length];`?  The class looks odd, thus the reason why you should state exactly what you're trying to accomplish with this `array` class.

Comment: `array<T1, l1 + l2> res;`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I certainly went through the long route. I am trying to implement ```array<int, 5> arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
arr1[0] = 0;
array<int, 5> arr2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
array<int, 10> arr3;
arr3 = arr1 + arr2; // arr3 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}``` in main(),

Answer (score 0):

template non type parameters should be constexpr values.

so you might do

```
template<class T1, int l1>
array<T1, l1 + l1> operator +( const array<T1, l1> &arr1, const array<T1, l1> &arr2 )
{
    constexpr int add = l1 + l1;
    array<T1, add> temp;
    // ........
}
```

Comment: There is no l2 defined here

Comment: Typo fixed. should be `l1` (or add `l2` parameter for `arr2`)

Comment: Can you give me an example how to add l2 in this

Comment: @ShadyD: `template<class T1, int l1, int l2>
array<T1, l1 + l2> operator +( const array<T1, l1> &arr1, const array<T1, l2> &arr2 )`.